# Why are my WordPress urls always opening to last published post?

Tags: php, wordpress

Every post permalink takes me to last published post.

For example both

```
http://randomwebsite.com/?p=554 and
http://randomwebsite.com/?p=556
```

Take me to same article, and it is always the newest post.

I tried changing permalink structure, and reinstalling WordPress, but still no go.

It is very strange problem and I never had it before.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Could be an issue in your template, try using the default one and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joren mentioned in the comments, this sounds like it could be a template problem. That is, your `post` data may be loaded as it should, and your permalink structure may be fine, but if the posts are being routed to a template file which is hard-coded to display only a single (most recent post) then you will have this problem.

You can confirm this is in fact the problem by switching to another, more standard theme, (like twentytwelve,twentythirteen...) and verify that the issue is resolved.

If that indeed does fix the problem. Try to determine which template file is being loaded in *your* theme by digging around in the source (the files are found here: wp-content/your-theme/*template-file.php*) or by reading this page of the WP documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy. Then debug the code as necessary.

Comment: @Rahil this really depends. It could be any number or combination of template files,  The only *required* template file is `index.php`; the others are optional. Please see the link in my Answer.